# Why does my image overlap with my words?

Tags: css, media-queries

Why are my images overlapping my words? Below is the CSS of 5 different images and 1 table.

```
#memberreporthistoryimage1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:20%;

}

   #memberreporthistoryimage2 {
       position:absolute;
       left:40%;

}

      #memberreporthistoryimage3 {
          position:absolute;
          left:60%;

}

         #memberreporthistoryimage4 {
             position:absolute;
             left:30%;
           margin-top:20%;
}

            #memberreporthistoryimage5 {
                position:absolute;
                left:50%;
                margin-top:20%;
}

    #memberreporthistorytable2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;

}
```

as you can see i used my position as absolute. Therefore if i have not mistaken, the position of my second table should be going according to my image width and height since the memberreporthistorytable2 is below my images. Unfortunately, it doesn't. As you can see from the image below, it overlaps as soon as i click some data.

This is the layout when no data is being clicked

[image]

Here is the image where it overlap.

[image]

I tried adding the margin-top which obviously will extend the distance of the table from the images. However, i'm trying to make it look dynamic. Which means, the table 2 will change accordingly automatically when i clicked a data.

```
    #memberreporthistorytable2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:30%;
}
```

Under my source code

```
<tr>
        <td id="memberreporthistoryimage1">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td id="memberreporthistoryimage2">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td id="memberreporthistoryimage3">
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td id="memberreporthistoryimage4">
            <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td id="memberreporthistoryimage5">
            <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I have placed all my image in a td. All the td are under a tr. So i believe by wrapping my picture 1 by 1 and placing it to the place i want doesn't work as it is what i have been doing.

May i ask where have i done wrong to let it change the position dynamically apart from the position absolute?

Regards.

Comment: it is because the absolute positioning I guess

Comment: may i ask how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're **absolute positioning** for images.  Better wrap those images inside a div, then place it where you want.

Comment: Please view my updated question. I have added a vital point of adding an individual css for each image.